# Steam Web API get all genres of app?

Tags: javascript, json, steam

I'm trying to make a fun little program that incorporates showing information about steam games, but I'm not sure how to get all the genres of a specific game.

For this example I'll be using Borderlands 2.

This first image is from the steam store (https://store.steampowered.com/app/49520/Borderlands_2/)

[image: steam store tags]

This second image is from the web api (https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=49520)

[image: steam web api tags]

Why is it that it only has 2 genres on the webapi but way more on the steam store? Is there another place I can use to get the rest of the genres?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any documented (be it officially or unofficially) API function that will allow you to read all genres of an App.

Since you were asking for another place to get rest of the genres, did you consider scraping the data straight from the Steam Store page? Assuming you use NodeJS, getting the data with something like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) should be easy enough.

But: be aware that the page you are scraping from might change at any point in time without any notice. Of course, the same applies to the API you were considering to use, which is under development, not officially documented, and meant to be used internally by Steam.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you posted is of community defined store tags and not genre data. I have not been able to find the store tag data as part of a publicly available API.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot doesn't show genres, but tags. You can get tags with [steam cmd](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options). Of the ready-made solutions for getting json information about the game, i.e. tags, I can offer this https://www.steamcmd.net/#docs or [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/steamcmd/api).

[Json tags id](https://files.catbox.moe/96bty7.json) (there may not be all, tags can be added over time) I got from [steamdb](https://steamdb.info/tags/) although they do not allow it.

I don't like that in steam tags and genres can repeat in one and the same. Or some tags fit under genres and vice versa.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).